# How do I hook ws2_32.connect on Windows XP?

Tags: delphi, winapi, hook, winsock

I've been hooking ws2_32's `connect` function in external processes. I simply create the process with `CREATE_SUSPENDED` and then inject the "hook.dll" into the process to hook the `connect` function. Everything works fine on Windows 7 x64 and I used about 5 different hooking libraries (MagicAPIHook, UALLHook, AFXCodeHook, GenCodeHook, DetourHook, etc.). However, it seems *not* to work on Windows XP at all. All other API functions seem to work fine on Windows XP (`MessageBox`, `CreateProcess`, `VirtualAlloc`, etc.). How do I hook `connect`?

Comment: Assuming all that, I think we need more info. What sort of hooking are you using? What is the target process? How do you know the target process is calling connect? How can we reproduce?

Comment: There are some differences in M$ API for 32 and 64 Windows included completely different functions for getting same results. IMO you can be more clear what functions you are calling on which platform and what you are expecting.

Comment: I see. Yes I have been hooking the connect function in ws2_32. I used APIMonitor and the process calls the low level connect function from the ws2_32.dll (through wininet.dll). I used MagicAPIHook, UALLHook, AFXCodeHook, GenCodeHook, DetourHook, etc.

Comment: First of all: bits of host OS and application must be same. As for me: I does not seems XP-64 anywhere because of its buggy. Instead of Win7-64 which is the best M$ solution for computers with 64-bit architecture :) BTW in my Win7-64 all process even 32-bit shows that it loaded and used c:\windows\syswow64\ws32_32.dll instead of same library in the system32 folder. So, IMO, you must distribute 2 versions: for 32 and 64-bits OSes. And, may be somebody explain to me, how to post comments, which is not exactly answer, but which is lager then allows comments? :)

Comment: Sorry but I was talking about Windows XP 32bit.

Comment: So, as I understand, your application "works fine on Windows 7 x64" but "it seems not to work on Windows XP at all." on XP-32 according your suggestion? So what bitness (bit capacity) of your binaries: 32 or 64? If app 32bit works on Win7-64 but not works on WinXP-32 - this is question to MSDN.

Comment: the hookdll, the host and the external process are all 32bit.

Comment: @BenjaminWeiss It is time to public some your source code for now. I working frequently with WinAPI for now, but I have problems with 32x apps on 64x OS, not vice versa. But I believe, somebody here have decision for you. Good luck.